# How to retrieve value from multidimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

What's the simplest way to retrieve `English` from this array by providing `en`?

```
LANGUAGES = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ['Deutsch', 'de']
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Array#rassoc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) fits your use case perfectly.

```
LANGUAGES = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ['Deutsch', 'de']
]
LANGUAGES.rassoc("en")[0]
=> "English"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to access it from the code to the language: how about using a hash?

```
LANGUAGES = {
  'en' => 'English',
  'de' => 'Deutsch'
}
LANGUAGES['en']
=> "English"
```

Comment: Five years later I realise this is what I ended up doing.